# Use reserve word as a object

Tags: json, vb.net, keyword

I need to define a object called *end*, because I catch some data from a JSON file:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class profesionales


Private _idResource As Integer
Private _resourceName As String
Private _start As String
Private _End As DateTime
...

'This should be End buy is a keyword
 Public Property theEnd As DateTime

    Get
        Return _End
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)

        _End = value
    End Set

End Property
```

The JSON file

```
[{"idResource":1477,"resourceName":"Juan Llovet Garc\u00EDa","start":"08/07/2013 9:00","end":"08/07/2013 14:00"},{"idResource":1477,"resourceName":"Juan Llovet Garc\u00EDa","start":"08/07/2013 17:00","end":"08/07/2013 20:00"}]
```

How can I catch the date *end*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an identifier with the same name as a keyword using brackets:

```
public Property [End] As DateTime
```

This leads to confusing code and should be avoided where possible.